# Flex keeps wrapping even after nowrap?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

What I'm trying to achieve is a 4 block layout. 2 blocks having width 50% occupy the first section while the second section is followed by 2 other blocks.

I'm using `flex` for this so if I do it so that the flex-container takes up 100% width and height then on no-wrap the space of 50% should be taken up by the blocks here my markup and css.

Instead it still wraps and occupies one segment

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.col {} 
.red {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}
.blue {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: cadetblue;
}
.aqua {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: aqua;
}
.yellow {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <div id="container">

    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>

    <div class="aqua"></div>
    <div class="yellow"></div>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's an image on what I am trying to achieve.
[Click here for the flex box model i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8P2m.png)

Comment: Seems to be working fine. Nothing wrapping here. Maybe post images of problem and outcome you want.

Comment: @CodeiSir, you may also want to correct the [flex] tag in your pending edit. Needs to be [flexbox] ([flex] is something else).

Comment: @Michael_B Here is what I'm trying to achieve http://i.stack.imgur.com/f8P2m.png

Comment: So all you need to do is make `flex-wrap: wrap` (you have `nowrap`). That will achieve the layout in your image. But your question seems to contradict this goal.

Comment: @Michael_B Sorry i had the wrong conception about Wrap i though wrap means that the browser will automatically manipulate the width and height so it all fits into one screen. So i did a no-wrap so it doesn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `wrap` instead of `nowrap` and use `flex: 0 0 50%` instead of `width: 50%`.

`flex: 0 0 50%` stands for:

- `flex-grow: 0`: the div will not grow more than its basis
- `flex-shrink: 0`: the div will not shrink more than its basis
- `flex-basis: 50%`: the basic size of the box is 50% of its flex parent

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.col {} 
.red {
  height: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  background-color: red;
}
.blue {
  height: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  background-color: cadetblue;
}
.aqua {
  height: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  background-color: aqua;
}
.yellow {
  height: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <div id="container">

    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>

    <div class="aqua"></div>
    <div class="yellow"></div>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```